# How to add calculated columns and perform Calculations with IronPython Script in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, tibco, spotfire

I am using this script (below) to create a calculate column [NEWCOLUMN] in Spotfire using IronPython:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import CalculatedColumn

cols = Document.Data.Tables["TIBER"].Columns

cols.AddCalculatedColumn("NEWCOLUMN");
```

How do I control the datatype of the calculated column? Also, then what is the processes to edit the expression of the calculated column? For example, I would like NEWCOLUMN = [oldcolumn]*3.289

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculated column will inherit the data type from the expression in `<arg2>` of `AddCalculatedColumn(<arg1>,<arg2>)`.

i.e.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import CalculatedColumn
cols = Document.Data.Tables["TIBER"].Columns
cols.AddCalculatedColumn("NEWCOLUMN","[oldcolumn] * 3.289");
```

Roll Tide.

Comment: this is great! Is there any chance you could direct me to good documentation or learning material to learn IronPython scripting for Spotfire. I have many more calculations that I'd like to do to avoid having 35 different calculated columns, but am struggling to find good learning material

Comment: I wouldn't say good, or bad, just depends on how confusing it is to you but the API is really the only thing out there. I think it's pretty cumbersome sometimes. https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/api/Index.aspx

Comment: So here is the reference you needed explicitly: ...well that didn't work like intended but if you search on AddCalculatedColumn and select the last one in the list on the left you'll see the C construct.

Comment: are we limited in what we can do with an IronPython script? For example I have the calculation: 

Rank([K/Phi],"desc",[WELLNAME],"ties.method=first") 

that I use in a calculated column but I can't figure out how to incorporate into IronPython calculated column script you suggested (including the documentation you sent), how this would be incorporated?

Comment: There are no doubt limitations, but in your expression you just need to escape the quotes inside your expression. `cols.AddCalculatedColumn("NEWCOLUMN","Rank([K/Phi],\"desc\",[WELLNAME],\"ties.method=first\") ")`